# Using simple JS within ionic sidemenu sample (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am currently porting a Javascript "app" into AngularJS and one part of this app would be too long to recode.

What I would like to do is to use a simple javascript instruction like alert("message") within the ionic sideMenu sample available here : http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/

I already tried by including this into indext.html as well as in search.html but nothing would help

```
<script src="js/test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This is my test.js (I get no output for the console.log neither)

```
function test()
{
   console.log('test');
   alert("Secon test");
}
test(); //first method for calling the function, won't work
```

And calling it within an attribute won't work neither :

```
<ion-content class="has-header"  scroll="false" onload="test()">
```

Could you please tell me why this is not working and how to fix it?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Ionic uses angular so this should be included inside a controller

Comment: Thank you, it was stupid of me. I just hope setAttribute and getElementsByTagName will still be alright with AngularJS (I'm a beginner)

Comment: In general you won't use either of those unless you are creating a directive.  You may want to read about Angular before diving into Ionic.

Comment: I'm with a full JS search app, it will be long to port (especially because of how the data is formatted in it) but I have no choice it seems. I will skip the dirty solution after my previous try. Thank you for your comments

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned Lucuma :
Ionic uses angular so this should be included inside a controller.